# .style .backgroundColor error

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

Here is my script (in Selenium IDE):

```
storeEval |   var form =window.document.forms[0];

elements = form.elements; for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
{window.document.getElementsByTagName("elements").item(i).style.backgroundColor}
| result
```

here is my error:

```
[error] Threw an exception: window.document.getElementsByTagName("elements").item(i) is null
```

Comment: post your code and create a fiddle, need more info to help you. now it seems that the "elements" object is not being fetched .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

`window.document.getElementsByTagName("elements").item(i).style.backgroundColor`

Just use this:

`elements[i].style.backgroundColor`

Comment: oh, big thanks. Sorry for my stupid mistake. I feel ashamed – user1211063

Comment: `document.forms[0]` is just a shortcut for the first form on a page (forms is an array of all the forms), and elements is a shortcut to an array of all the input tags in that form - so there is no need to "get" them again, they are already selected for you in the dom...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is looking for elements of type `element`, like this:

```
<element>Something</element>
```

but there aren't any in the document.

Did you really mean to search for `<element>` elements?  It looks like the content of your loop wants to be something like this:

```
elements.item(i).style.backgroundColor
```